# How to overwrite a multiline string in bash?

Tags: bash, echo, overwrite

I have this code snippet, which allows to overwrite a string in bash if used multiple times:

```
echo -ne "String 1  \r"
echo -ne "String 2  \r"
```

Output:

```
String 2
```

However, the string is not overwritten if the string is wider than the terminal window:

```
echo -ne "Very very long string without any embedded newline charactes that is longer than the window width  \r"
echo -ne "String 2  \r"
```

Output:

```
Very very long string without any embedded newline charactes that is longer than the window width
String 2
```

How can I force overwrite for the entire string, independent of the terminal window's size?

Helpful answers do not:

- assume that I do not write until the bottom of the terminal window (see above requirement regarding independence of window size)
- assume that clear may be used in this context

Comment: the command you've provided does not overwrite anything ... it prints `String   ` and then the `\r` moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line; to move the cursor 'back', 'up', etc consider looking at `tput`

Comment: @markp-fuso I think the point is that if you do it repeatedly, each one overwrites the last because `\r` goes to the beginning.

Comment: @markp-fuso `-n` prevents it from going to the next line after printing.

Comment: @markp-fuso How does using `tput` help? You need to know if the line wrapped so you know how many lines up to go.

Comment: @markp-fuso It's like Barmar said, when used in a loop, it will go back to the beginning of a line (under certain cirumstances as it seems).

Comment: @kaiyazeera the current sample code doesn't overwrite anything; if you're using the code in a loop consider updating the question with a more representative example, including an example that demonstrates the subject *'... multiline string`*

Comment: @Barmar subject mentions 'multiline string' which (to me) implies an embedded `\n`, but with the `echo -n` and `\r` it looks (to me) like OP is trying to retrace back to the beginning of the (multiline ?) output; `tput` wouldn't need to know how many lines to move 'up' if using `tput sc/rc` (and assuming the output doesn't force the console/window to scroll); then again, these are only my (mis)understandings based on a poorly described problem and sample code that (likely?) doesn't demo the issue

Comment: There's no embedded `\n`. It's multiline because it's longer than the terminal width, so it automatically wraps to the next line.

Comment: Read the whole question, not just the title: "the string is not overwritten if the string is wider than the terminal window." @markp-fuso

Comment: sorry @markp-fuso, I really can't add anything to the content because that is what it is. Please re-read the question. There is no embedded `\n` and it doesn't make sense to provide an example given that everyone uses different font and window sizes.

Comment: `echo -e '\e[1A\e[KString 2'`

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- code generates output that may display on more than one line in the console/window (either multi-line variable w/ embedded carriage returns or just a really long line that causes a wrap when it hits the 'end' of the console/window)
- output does not cause the terminal to 'scroll up' (eg, program does not start printing output in the last line of the console/window
- do not know how many console/windows lines will contain the output string

First thing we'll do is provide a string that's actually longer than my console/window.

```
# 'stty -a' shows my terminal width ('columns') is 87, so 200 should be a long-enough string to play with

$ printf -v longstring '%0.sx' {1..200}
$ echo "${#longstring}:${longstring}"
200:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

To simulate 'backing up to front of line' we can use `tput`, eg:

```
erase=$(tput el)                  # save control codes for 'clear to end of line'
clear                             # clear console/window to insure we're not generating output at/near bottom of console/window

printf "\n\n################ begin output"

tput sc                           # save current cursor position

for i in {1..5}
do
    printf -v count "%0s" $i
    echo -en "${count} ${longstring} EOS\r"
    tput rc                       # move cursor back to our save point
    sleep 1

    printf "${count} short string${erase}"
    tput rc
    sleep 1
done

# pick enough `\n` to get us 'past' our lines of output

printf "\n\n\n################ end output"
```

On the first pass through the loop we see:

```
########### start test
01 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx EOS
```

And one second later we see:

```
########### start test
01 short string
```

On subsequent passes through the loop the output line is overwritten with `02 xxx...`, `02 short string`, `03 xxx...`, `03 short string`, `04 xxx...`, `04 short string`, `05 xxx...` and then finally:

```
########### start test
05 short string


########### end test
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce for generic use. `printf -v str '%0.sx' {1..200}; echo "onetime string:"; echo -en "$str";echo "starts";tput sc;echo -en "${str} \r";tput rc;echo -en "${str} \r";tput rc;echo -en "${str} \r";tput rc;printf "\r\n end" ` produces differing numbers of x-lines

Comment: But I appreciate your answer!

Comment: works with the example from your question; consider updating the question with an example that's more representative of what you're doing IRL

Comment: I ran your code (from your comment) ... works as expected ... one long line of `xxx's` with `starts` appended on the end, cursor moves to next line (here you run `tput sc`), the follow-on commands overwrite the same set of lines each time (but they do *not* overwrite the initial set of `xxxxx.start` since that was performed on lines *before* you ran `tput sc`; net result, the code from your comment functions as expected; consider updating the question with details about your OS, shell, terminal type and `tput -V`

Comment: There may be reasons why users do not provide their original code. The example is representative enough and my comment shows that your solution is too easy to break to be used in scripts that work with variable strings.

Comment: bash, solution should work on multiple Linux versions (e.g. Ubuntu, Arch, ...) as well as do not require specific versions of any tool used. The code I posted above prints the string before start correct, but then another string with 2 lines of x's too much.

Comment: actually, it seems to works correct half of the times. It seems indeterministic and may be dependend on window height .

Comment: if you can't use `clear` then just make sure you don't run your code at/near the bottom of your console/window; as for the extra `x's` ... did you read/understand the entire answer? I don't see you referencing the `tput ed / ${erase}` portion of the answer so, yeah, you're left with a bunch of unwanted x's at the end (because you didn't `${erase}` them)

Comment: That seems not acceptable.

Comment: ***what*** is not acceptable?'

Comment: Yes I did understand your answer, but your solutions seems to be indeterministic and is thus not what I am looking for.

Comment: Not acceptable to use clear or not write until the bottom of the console window

Comment: your sample code (from the comment) works exactly as expected; if you want different results you'll need to work on the code; 'not acceptable' ...  tput/curses has some limitations when programming at the bash level so if you need more control you'll likely need to look at writing in another language that allows full cursor control on the console/window

Comment: The erase does not make any difference regarding the indeterminism. And yes, I read your answer, but you actually edited it and thus I answered to your first version.

Comment: Please consider adding the limitations to your answer then?

Comment: the erase., when used correctly with tput/rc, effectively clears the slate and starts you right back at 'the beginning' (tput/sc); there's nothing 'indeterminisitic' about your (comment) sample code ... works as expected each time it's run

Comment: there are no limitations I need to add to the answer; see the assumptions; if the assumptions do not apply then you'll need to update your question with more specifics (thus eliminating the need for others to make assumptions about your environment)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'Very very long string without any embedded newline charactes that is longer than the window width'

echo -e '\e[1A\e[KString 2'

String 2
```

> return to the previous line using \e[1A and clear that line using
> \e[K

##### Test

```
for((i=2000; i>=0; i -=25))
do
  sleep 0.01
  echo -e "\e[1A\e[KString $i"
done
```